# How to add a user defined variable into a list of columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to groupby few variables in python where I have my hardcoded variables and also user-defined variables, I want to merge all the variables into one and use that as a single list, I tried the following but cannot arrive at a solution

```
user_vars='abc','def','hij'
It returns me 

('abc','def','hij')
```

and I want to use the above three variables while doing groupby in my program

```
g=df.groupby(['date','Language',user_vars,'genre']['key'].sum().reset_index()
```

That's How I am trying to put the user-defined variables for grouping but as the "user_vars" object has become a tuple, a whole tuple is getting passed instead of one variable after the other

The required Output is:

```
g=df.groupby(['date','Language','abc','def','hij','genre']['key'].sum().reset_index()
```

But I am getting it like:

```
g=df.groupby(['date','Language',('abc','def','hij'),'genre']['key'].sum().reset_index()
```

And that's why I am getting the error.

Answer (score 2):

You should unpack the tuple when passing its parameters using the *operator

```
g=df.groupby(['date','Language', *user_vars, 'genre']['key'].sum().reset_index()
```